# Change Equation E(T,u) and N(T,u) in T(E,N) and u(E,N)

Tags: list-manipulation, interpolation

I am pretty new on mathematica and I have three functions, each defined by an analytic expression:

```
Nf = 2.5;
p0 = ((16 + 10.5 Nf)*π^2)/90;
ζ = M/T;
p[T_, M_] = T^4 (p0 + Nf (1/18 (ζ)^2 + 1/(324*π^2) (ζ)^4)) //FullSimplify;
e[T_, M_] = 3 p[T, M] // FullSimplify;
n[T_, M_] = D[p[T, M], M] // FullSimplify;
```

I have these equations, but I need to create a new table with `T` as a function of `e` and `n` and `M` (for $\mu$).

I heard that I have to make a table of these functions; for example, this one:

```
Table[{T, M, n[T, M]}, {T, 0, 1., 0.1}, {M, 0, 1, 0.1}]
```

And after I have to do an interpolation. However, I don't know how to do this for the correct variables and how to have the correct table at the end. That is, I want to create a table like this:

```
Table[{e, n, T[e, n], M[e,n]}, {e, 0, 1., 0.1}, {n, 0, 1, 0.1}]
```

I then want to export this out to a file and set a different step for `e`

Comment: Basically, you want to invert a function / solve an equation for T as a function of e and n. It seems to me, however, that there would be many solutions to that high-order polynomial equation. You will need to define which one to choose.

Comment: I guess this is two equations with two unknowns, that mustbe only one solution isn't it ?

Comment: Consider `Solve[{x^3 + y == 1, x^3 - y == 2}, {x, y}]`. Those are also two equations and two unknowns, but of course as you can see when you run that code, there are three sets of solutions because the equations involved a third-degree polynomial. You should be able to decide which solution is relevant to you .

Comment: Indeed, I understood. I can choose one solution without problem with the different physics conditions I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Nf = 5/2;
p0 = ((16 + 21/2 Nf)*π^2)/90;
ζ = M/T;

p[T_, M_] = 
  T^4 (p0 + Nf (1/18 (ζ)^2 + 1/(324*π^2) (ζ)^4)) // Simplify;

e[T_, M_] = 3 p[T, M] // Simplify;

n[T_, M_] = D[p[T, M], M] // Simplify;
```

Data for multidimensional interpolation needs to be in the form: `{{{x1, y1,…}, f1}, {{x2, y2,…}, f2},…}`. Consequently, use

**EDIT:** Increased range for `M` to extend interpolation range for `n`. (Thanks to **Akku14**)

```
fT = Interpolation[
  Table[
    {{e[T, M], n[T, M]}, T},
    {T, 0, 1, 0.01}, {M, 0, 3.25, 0.01}] //
   Flatten[#, 1] &,
  InterpolationOrder -> 1]
```

[image]

The [`InterpolationOrder`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolationOrder.html) is restricted to `1` since the `{e, n}` grid is unstructured (non-uniform). Then function `fT` can be plotted directly

```
Plot3D[fT[ev, nv], {ev, 0, 1}, {nv, 0, 1},
 AxesLabel ->
  (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@
    {"e[T, M]", "n[T, M]", "T"}),
 PlotRange -> {-1.5, 0.55},
 PlotPoints -> 50,
 ClippingStyle -> None]
```

[image]

You get similar results from a [`Table`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html)

```
data = Table[{ev, nv, fT[ev, nv]}, {ev, 0, 1, 0.02}, {nv, 0, 1, 
      0.02}] // Flatten[#, 1] &; // Quiet

ListPlot3D[data,
 AxesLabel ->
  (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {"e[T, M]", "n[T, M]", "T"}),
 PlotRange -> {-1.5, 0.55},
 ClippingStyle -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry @Bob Hanlon, but most of the shown T-values are roughly extrapolated and not valid, because fT is only interpolated for  `0 < n < .28 `

Comment: @Akku14 - Thanks. Increased range for `M` to extend interpolation range for `n`

Answer (score 2):

Why not eliminate M from equations and solve for T.

```
eli = Eliminate[ee == e[T, M] && nn == n[T, M], M];

TT[ee_, nn_] = 
    T /. Solve[eli && nn > 0 && ee > 0 && 0 < T, T, Reals] // 
              FullSimplify

{*   {ConditionalExpression[
Root[-108000 ee^3 + 1476225 nn^4 \[Pi]^2 + 
 1093500 ee nn^2 \[Pi]^2 #1^2 + 51300 ee^2 \[Pi]^2 #1^4 + 
 510300 nn^2 \[Pi]^4 #1^6 + 118440 ee \[Pi]^4 #1^8 + 
 33124 \[Pi]^6 #1^12 &, 2], 
 ee > 0 && 0 < nn < Root[-160 ee^3 + 2187 \[Pi]^2 #1^4 &, 2]]} *}

Plot3D[TT[e, n], {e, 0, 30}, {n, 0, 3}, AxesLabel -> {e, n, T}]
```

[image]

Comment: For T it seems works, however when I did the same thing for M, I don't have anything on the Plot3D

Comment: What do you mean with "when I did the same thing for M"  ?

Comment: I eliminate T from equations and Solve for M. ```eli2 = Eliminate[ee2 == e[T, M] && nn2 == n[T, M], T]``` and ```MM[ee_, nn_] = 
 M /. Solve[eli2 && nn2 > 0 && ee2 > 0 && 0 < M, M, Reals] // 
  FullSimplify```

Comment: Be carefull with function definitions. Use `MM[ee2_,nn2_] =` since you changed to ee2,nn2.

Comment: Indeed, my bad. However I don't know if I can use this method because when I try to export in a Table, I have many Undefined element in this Table ```Table[{e, n, TT[e, n], MM[e, n]}, {e, 0, 1, 0.1}, {n, 0, 1, 0.1}]```

Comment: The condition `0 < nn < Root[-160 ee^3 + 2187 \[Pi]^2 #1^4 &, 2] ` in TT restricts nn to very small values for ee < 1 in order to get real solutions.